# Is there a way to make an HTML5 input range receive focus in Safari when it's used?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Safari (at least v14) doesn't seem to support focussing on an input range. Even if I use javascript to manually focus on the DOM element it loses focus just as soon as you begin moving the range handle. Is there a way to force Safari to receive focus and stay focussed while it's being used? Other browsers like Chrome and Firefox appear to preserve focus while in use.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var range = document.getElementById("range");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var log = function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, e.target.type);
};

document.addEventListener("focusin", log);
document.addEventListener("focusout", log);

text.addEventListener("focus", log);
text.addEventListener("blur", log);

range.addEventListener("focus", log);
range.addEventListener("blur", log);

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  range.focus();
});
```

```css
input {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<label>Range <input tabindex="0" id="range" type="range" value="50" /></label>
<button id="button" type="button">Focus</button>
<br />
<label>Text <input tabindex="1" id="text" type="text" value="Text" /></label>
```

Comment: Could be an option to manually implement focus? I mean, you can manually change input style based on many events. I know it does not seem ideal, but native inputs are historically broken.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I can manually focus it but then it loses focus as soon as the range slider begins to move.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano The problem also might not be the style alone, but e.g. in my case, when the previously selected text input gets the focus back, and the Android cellphone opens a keyboard every time again. So after every click on the slider you have to close that keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it isn't supported, you can wrap the input range inside of an element with a tabindex and fake the same effect.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var range = document.getElementById("range");
var label = document.getElementById("label");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var log = function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, e.target.type || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase());
};

document.addEventListener("focusin", log);
document.addEventListener("focusout", log);

text.addEventListener("focus", log);
text.addEventListener("blur", log);

range.addEventListener("focus", log);
range.addEventListener("blur", log);

label.addEventListener("focus", log);
label.addEventListener("blur", log);

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  range.focus();
});
```

```css
input {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

input:focus,
#label:focus input {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

#label:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="label" tabindex="-1">Range <input tabindex="0" id="range" type="range" value="50" /></span>
<button id="button" type="button">Focus</button>
<br />
<label>Text <input tabindex="1" id="text" type="text" value="Text" /></label>
```